# Text to speech function is not working in my Listview

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

In my listview I have text and one button as text to speech button.After clicking the button audio is not coming.ssssafter clicking the button audio of text to speech conversion is  not working.

Myactivity.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item); 

        mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        mDbHelper.open();
         Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
         if(projectsCursor.getCount()>0)
           {
           fillData(projectsCursor);

           Log.i("filling", "...");
           }
           else
           {
                new GetDataAsyncTask().execute();
           }


        btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        //praycount.setOnClickListener(this);
        //initView();

}





    /*private void initView(){
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://www.ginfy.com/api/v1/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);


    }   */



    private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
            Dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            /*mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this); // initialize mDbHelper before.
            mDbHelper.open();
            Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
            if(projectsCursor.getCount()>0)
            {
            fillData(projectsCursor);
            }*/
            for(int i=0; i<ID.size(); i++){
                mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                 mDbHelper.open();
                 mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(ID.get(i),TITLE.get(i),CONTENT.get(i),COUNT.get(i)));
                 }
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            getData();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void getData() {
          try
          {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://ginfynetwork-s9k4z6piks.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/posts.json");
      // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mbbangalore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");     

      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
      HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
      String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
       Log.i("................",_response);
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
      JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");//(url);
          for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
              JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
              String id = c.getString("id");
              String title = c.getString("title");
              String  content = c.getString("content");
              String  count = c.getString("count");
              //mDbHelper=new GinfyDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);
              //mDbHelper.open();
              //mDbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new Category(id,title,content,count));
              ID.add(id);
              TITLE.add(title);
              CONTENT.add(content);
              COUNT.add(count);
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       private void fillData(Cursor projectsCursor) {
           //mDbHelper.open();   

           if(projectsCursor!=null)
           {
           String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};
           int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text1, R.id.count};
            dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
             this, R.layout.activity_row, 
             projectsCursor, 
             from, 
             to,
             0);
            setListAdapter(dataAdapter);

            EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
              myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               }

               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                 int count, int after) {
               }

               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                 int before, int count) {
                   dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
               }
              });

              dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                     public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                         return mDbHelper.fetchProjectByName(constraint.toString());
                     }
                 });






            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id) {                    
                   if(arg1.getId()== R.id.btnaudioprayer && arg1.isClickable() ){


                         btnaudioprayer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer);

                               txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,txtText .getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       speakOut();

                    }    
                }        
            }); 




           }else
           {
               Log.i("...........","null");
           }

       }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
   public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```

This is my text to speech function code for my listview.

Logcat error showing like this

```
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity.onInit(MainActivity.java:289)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.dispatchOnInit(TextToSpeech.java:640)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.access$1000(TextToSpeech.java:52)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.onServiceConnected(TextToSpeech.java:1297)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1101)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1118)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-16 09:51:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(905):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting NPE

You have this below

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id) {  
    if(arg1.getId()== R.id.btnaudioprayer && arg1.isClickable() ){
        btnaudioprayer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer); // initialized on list item click.
```

And you have this

```
btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true); // inside init
```

Your `btnaudioprayer` is not initialized until list item click

When you click button in each row of listview it causes NPE cause your actually clicking button and not listview row items.

Use a Custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        int row_id = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");  //Your row id (might need to replace)
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        int col1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("title");
        String title = cursor.getString(col1 );
        int col2 = cursor.getColumnIndex("content");
        final String content = cursor.getString(col2 );
        //  TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        // cursor.getColumnName(1)
        tv.setText( title);
        tv1.setText( content);
        // tv2.setText( ""+cursor.getColumnIndex(GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT));
        // String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT}
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //ADD STUFF HERE you know which row is clicked. and which button
                typed = content;
                speakOut();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, parent, false);

        bindView(v,context,cursor);
        return v;
    }

}
```

In your `filldata` method

```
String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_COUNT};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text2, R.id.text1, R.id.count};
dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter (MainActivity.this, pct, projectsCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

speakOut

```
private void speakOut() { 
    tts.speak(typed, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Your class implements `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`

```
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            // btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: ,dude how to solve the same error in custom listview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723438/nullpointerexception-while-using-tts-in-customlistview

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not calling overridden method of `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`...

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }
```

Steps to solve the problem.. :-

- Make sure you have implemented TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
- override `onInit()` method as show above... *Your onInit1 method wont work*

Hope this helps... Also refer [here for sample](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/)

Comment: dude i initialized all the things ,i followed that tutorial only .check thisurl http://pastebin.com/cGWV4HL9

Comment: check my second point, you are using `onInit1` which is user defined & it won't get called...

Comment: I changed onInit1 into onInit thats ok or anyother changes need

Comment: after changing like that what you said,it showing logcat error,application has stopped

Comment: @KarthickM at which line are you getting nullpointer Exception

Comment: btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true); @CRUSADER

Comment: Thats b'cause btnaudioprayer is null. Try adding `btnaudioprayer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer);` inside onCreate() method

Comment: but that button only in activity_row not in the activiyt_list_item.

Comment: Took an effort of going through your code, I realized that you are not even using `btnaudioprayer` InageButton atall. Its seems its only for display prupose I guess as no `onClick` is there. Comment the line you are getting exception, its not required for you then...

Comment: No dude,actually using that function in listview,the fetching of listview from db,so i cant give that click function in oncreate thats why i gave like that one,have you seen my full code dude http://pastebin.com/cGWV4HL9 @CRUSADER

Comment: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long id) {                    
             if(arg1.getId()== R.id.btnaudioprayer && arg1.isClickable() ){
              
                
                btnaudioprayer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer);
              
                      txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,txtText .getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              speakOut();
      
     }

Comment: @KarthickM Have you read my last comment, I didn't say anything to do in onCreate, what I am suggesting is just comment that line .. like this.. `//btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true);`.. In that sample example, he required setEnable b'coz he was calling `speakOut();` method onClick of that button, that is not in your case as you are calling method on list click..

Comment: now it showing in this line dude  String text = txtText.getText().toString();

Comment: what the problem in that line dude

Comment: public TextView txtText; like that i assigned and then  txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1); like this dude i am having @CRUSADER

Comment: OK, now, let me ask question, `txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);` in which layout is `text1` is defined. If it is in `R.layout.activity_list_item` then put above line code in onCreate method.. and so on.. I am sure you can solve this.. For now, hardcode `txtText = "Android Speech"` and check if its TTS is working, so that you can accept the answer and close this question for now..

Comment: no its in activity_row dude,what hardcode not gettting you how to put that one @CRUSADER

Comment: GOSH!! was that so difficult to understand..?? Inside your `speakOut` method comment the first line and add `String text = "Android speech";` . I recommended this b'coz ur question was on TTS and I think its already solved. You can post why u getting Textview as null in different question altogether..

Comment: actually opening the screen itself the audio is coming,i have one button to go to that listview,and inside the listview there is contents and their button i want that if i click the button the audio of the respective contents text has to speak out.But rite now for going to listview want to click one button after click the button going to listview itself that audio is coming now

Comment: Happy to know, that your TTS issue is been resolved, mark the answer as solved for others to benefit, as far as, your layout structure is concern, post another question with proper details, there will be many like me who will help you in your quest...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723438/nullpointerexception-while-using-tts-in-customlistview  @CRUSADER